# Using multiple. gs files in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I am a newbie and learning app script. Is there a way where I can export and import functions from different .gs files?

In my `code.gs`, I have the code:

```
function test() {
    callMe("hello world")
}
```

and I have a helper.gs file where some functions live.

```
function callMe(msg) { Logger.log(msg) }
function quit() { Logger.log("quitting") }
```

Now, when I run the script, it throws an error:
`ReferenceError: msg is not defined`

Basically, I want to create helper functions and then export them so as to organize my code inside `code.gs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are not actually executing `test`.

Make sure the `test` function is selected for execution before you click the run button:

[image]

Comment: Right. Thank you, it worked. Btw, is it a better idea if I create multiple .gs files? Will that make the script slower?

Comment: The speed will be the same, but your code will be more structured if you separate it into multiple files. @Hansel